# Como fazer para requisitar arquivos dentro de diretórios que começam com ponto em Lua

Tags: arquivo, sintaxe, lua, path, caminho-relativo

Estou tentando requisitar scripts lua com base em um caminho "root". Porém ele converte todos os caracteres `.` em `\` na função `require`. Existe alguma funcionalidade que possa usar o caminho absoluto sem que substitua os caracteres `.` por `\`?

script:

```lua
root = os.getenv("USERPROFILE") .. "\\.dotfiles\\lua\\"
print("caminho correto: " .. root .. "\n")
require(root .. "options")
require(root .. "keymaps")
require(root .. "plugins")
require(root .. "colorscheme")
require(root .. "call-plugins")
```

saída:

```
caminho correto: C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\.dotfiles\lua\

Erro detectado ao processar C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:3: module 'C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\.dotfiles\lua\options' not
found:
        no field package.preload['C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\.dotfiles\lua\options']
        no file '.\C:\Users\55549\SAMSUNG-BOOK\\dotfiles\lua\options.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\C:\Users\55549\SAMSUNG-BOOK\\dotfiles\lua\options.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\C:\Users\55549\SAMSUNG-BOOK\\dotfiles\lua\options\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\C:\Users\55549\SAMSUNG-BOOK\\dotfiles\lua\options.luac'
        no file '.\C:\Users\55549\SAMSUNG-BOOK\\dotfiles\lua\options.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\C:\Users\55549\SAMSUNG-BOOK\\dotfiles\lua\options.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\C:\Users\55549.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\C:\Users\55549.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:3: in main chunk
Aperte ENTER ou digite um comando para continuar
```

Answer (score 0):

Lua busca os módulos pela variável `package.path`.
Por exemplo:

```lua
package.path = "C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\.dotfiles\\lua\\?.lua"
-- o caractere "?" é substituído pelo nome do módulo passado para o `require`.
```

considere a seguinte estrutura de diretórios que ele buscará pelos módulos:

```
C:
|- Users
    |- USUARIO
        |- .dotfiles
            |- lua
                |- NOME_DO_MODULO.lua
```

De tal maneira que o comando `require` busque com base nesse novo valor sem substituir os caracteres `.` por `\` (- somente caracteres que se encontram dentro da variável `package.path`).

Por exemplo:

```lua
package.path = "C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\.dotfiles\\lua\\?.lua"

require("options") 
-- CAMINHO: "C:\Users\USUARIO\.dotfiles\lua\options.lua"

require("plugins.nerdtree") 
-- CAMINHO: "C:\Users\USUARIO\.dotfiles\lua\plugins\nerdtree.lua"
--                            ^ não substituído    ^ substituído
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar adicionar na variável global o caminho root:
`LUA_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\.dotfiles\\lua'`